# Swagger Codegen - How to identify whether a property is nullable or not?

Tags: java, swagger, swagger-codegen

```
{
  "swagger": "2.0",
  "info": {
    "title": "Business Objects",
    "version": "1.0"
  },
  "host": "NA",
  "definitions": {
    "Customer": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "integer"
        },
        "name": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "isActive": {
          "type": "boolean"
        }
      },
      "required": [
        "id",
        "name",
        "isActive"
      ]
    }
  },
  "paths": {}
}
```

Above is the format `swagger-codegen-cli` will accept but according to [this](https://github.com/swagger-api/swagger-codegen/wiki/Mustache-Template-Variables) there is no variable to identify whether the property should be nullable or not. Is there anyway to workaround this?

Answer (score 0):

Had to resort to making a change in the program myself and now we are using that modified version in our builds.